# Design html table as gridView

Tags: html, css, gridview, html-table

I work with vb.net.
I have a gridView with an attribute "GridLines". When I do GridLines="Both" it mark the lines in some color and shape.
I want exactly the same design in a regular html table, through CSS.
How can I do it?

Comment: "I want exactly the same design in a regular html table", you need just look and feel? or you will also display data from the `DataSource`?

Comment: just look and feel.
In asp:GridView there is an attribute GridLines="Both".
I want the same effect in html table.

Thanks

Comment: You can add `border` to the `table` to achieve that.

Comment: I have added an answer, try it let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using applying class in gridview and set `GridLines="None"` as none.
here i give an example

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grid_patient" Style="width: 100%;" CssClass="salesGrid" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ProcessFocusedRowChangedOnServer="disable" >
```

and then your css like below

```
.salesGrid
        {
            font-size: 12px;                                
            overflow: hidden;
            border:1px solid #000000;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For bordering the cells of a table (as `GridLines="Both"` do), try the following.

Add a css class for the `table`. Let say the class name be `gridlines`. Then add the style as below,

```
.gridlines table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.gridlines table tr td
{
 padding:0;
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did something else. I just do "border= solid" in the table tag and it work. When I do "border: solid" in the css it do the out borders of the table.

Comment: @shlomi That's nice then :)